# Is there a way I can iterate this Excel formula using SEQUENCE or similar?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am currently trying to set up a dynamic formula, however, am coming up against a wall in my VSTACK. Realistically I want to SEQUENCE for each ROW in CATEGORIES.

This has truly stumped me, any help would be appreciated.

```
=LET(CATEGORIES,FILTER(UNIQUE(Sheet2!D:D),(UNIQUE(Sheet2!D:D)<>"Type")*(UNIQUE(Sheet2!D:D)<>0)),
VSTACK(
INDEX(CATEGORIES,1,0),
FILTER(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!D:D=INDEX(CATEGORIES,1,0)),
INDEX(CATEGORIES,2,0),
FILTER(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!D:D=INDEX(CATEGORIES,2,0)),
INDEX(CATEGORIES,3,0),
FILTER(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!D:D=INDEX(CATEGORIES,3,0)),
INDEX(CATEGORIES,4,0),
FILTER(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!D:D=INDEX(CATEGORIES,4,0)),
INDEX(CATEGORIES,5,0),
FILTER(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!D:D=INDEX(CATEGORIES,5,0)),
INDEX(CATEGORIES,6,0),
FILTER(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!D:D=INDEX(CATEGORIES,6,0)),
INDEX(CATEGORIES,7,0),
FILTER(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!D:D=INDEX(CATEGORIES,7,0)),
INDEX(CATEGORIES,8,0),
FILTER(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!D:D=INDEX(CATEGORIES,8,0)),
INDEX(CATEGORIES,9,0),
FILTER(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!D:D=INDEX(CATEGORIES,9,0)),
INDEX(CATEGORIES,10,0),
FILTER(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!D:D=INDEX(CATEGORIES,10,0)),
INDEX(CATEGORIES,11,0),
FILTER(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!D:D=INDEX(CATEGORIES,11,0)),
INDEX(CATEGORIES,12,0),
FILTER(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!D:D=INDEX(CATEGORIES,12,0)),
INDEX(CATEGORIES,13,0),
FILTER(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!D:D=INDEX(CATEGORIES,13,0)),
INDEX(CATEGORIES,14,0),
FILTER(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!D:D=INDEX(CATEGORIES,14,0)),
INDEX(CATEGORIES,15,0),
FILTER(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!D:D=INDEX(CATEGORIES,15,0)),
INDEX(CATEGORIES,16,0),
FILTER(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!D:D=INDEX(CATEGORIES,16,0)),
INDEX(CATEGORIES,17,0),
FILTER(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!D:D=INDEX(CATEGORIES,17,0)),
INDEX(CATEGORIES,18,0),
FILTER(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!D:D=INDEX(CATEGORIES,18,0)),
INDEX(CATEGORIES,19,0),
FILTER(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!D:D=INDEX(CATEGORIES,19,0)),
INDEX(CATEGORIES,20,0),
FILTER(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!D:D=INDEX(CATEGORIES,20,0)),
INDEX(CATEGORIES,21,0),
FILTER(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!D:D=INDEX(CATEGORIES,21,0)),
INDEX(CATEGORIES,22,0),
FILTER(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!D:D=INDEX(CATEGORIES,22,0)),
INDEX(CATEGORIES,23,0),
FILTER(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!D:D=INDEX(CATEGORIES,23,0)),
INDEX(CATEGORIES,24,0),
FILTER(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!D:D=INDEX(CATEGORIES,24,0)),
INDEX(CATEGORIES,25,0),
FILTER(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!D:D=INDEX(CATEGORIES,25,0))
))
```

LET CATEGORIESNo, ROWS(CATEGORIES) and CATEGORIESSEQ, SEQUENCE(CATEGORIES(No,1,1,1) ... no luck.

Comment: Does the filter return a 1 to 1 relation? or can it return multiple?

Comment: `=LET(CATEGORIES,FILTER(UNIQUE(Sheet2!D:D),(UNIQUE(Sheet2!D:D)<>"Type")*(UNIQUE(Sheet2!D:D)<>0)),HSTACK(CATEGORIES,FILTER(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!D:D=CATEGORIES)))`

Comment: The idea is that Sheet2 contains product details. In column D is the product category, and in B is the product name. The formula above creates a VSTACK, which picks the first category, followed by everything inside it, then the second category, and everything inside that.

Comment: Try: `=DROP(REDUCE("",FILTER(UNIQUE(Sheet2!D:D),(UNIQUE(Sheet2!D:D)<>"Type")*(UNIQUE(Sheet2!D:D)<>0)),LAMBDA(y,z,VSTACK(y,z,FILTER(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!D:D=z)))),1)`

Comment: This seems to work perfectly! I can't thank you enough but I'd love an explanation as to what is going on here. :D

Comment: See below for a formal answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use REDUCE:

```
=DROP(REDUCE("",FILTER(UNIQUE(Sheet2!D:D),(UNIQUE(Sheet2!D:D)<>"Type")*(UNIQUE(Sheet2!D:D)<>0)),LAMBDA(y,z,VSTACK(y,z,FILTER(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!D:D=z)))),1)
```

This will loop through the results of the first filter and VSTACK the results of the second filter with the old information and the item being searched.

REDUCE/LAMBDA does the iteration and returns a final result.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you want...

```
=LET(
  valuesRaw, Sheet2!B:B,
  categoriesRaw, Sheet2!D:D,
  categoriesUnique, UNIQUE(categoriesRaw),
  categories, TOROW(
    FILTER(
      categoriesUnique, 
      (categoriesUnique <> "Type")*(categoriesUnique <> 0)
    )
  ),
  BYCOL(
    categories,
    LAMBDA(category, VSTACK(
      category, 
      FILTER(
        valuesRaw,
        categoriesRaw = category
      )
    ))
  )
)
```

So what this does....

First, it gets `categories` the same way you did, except it uses `TOROW()` to explicitly turn it into a one-row table. This way we don't have to use `SEQUENCE` or any counters to iterate, we can just process each column of the one-row table via `BYCOL`.

`LAMBDA` is a newer function that lets you declare variables (in this case just `category`, one of the columns in `categories`) and the output (in this case a column of the provided category name appended by the values for that category).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This seems to return a #CALC! , however Scott's solution of =DROP(REDUCE("",FILTER(UNIQUE(Sheet2!D:D),(UNIQUE(Sheet2!D:D)<>"Type")*(UNIQUE(Sheet2!D:D)<>0)),LAMBDA(y,z,VSTACK(y,z,FILTER(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!D:D=z)))),1) worked perfectly... I can't seem to decipher it though.

Comment: @Thiv"however Scott's solution..." does what? works? does not work? is better than your original?

Comment: Weird. It works perfectly for me in Google Sheets and I've never had a compatibility issue between Excel and Sheets for these functions before.